# Can't signOut of Google OAuth2

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am not able to use the Google signOut() to sign me out of an oAuth session I am signed into.

As an example, I have pasted the below code taken directly from the Google quick start site...
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js

I have saved it to a 1.htm file on a website and am attempting to drive the Google API.

When I use the OAuth 2.0 client ID (not shown in the attached code) from my API console, I am able to login and see my calendar events.  However, when the Sign Out button is clicked, I don't get logged out.

[image]

Right after clicking Sign Out, the following code is running for sure...

[image]

But then, it doesn't sign me out. Running from the Console, I see it still thinks I am logged in...
[image]

I am listening for any changes to status on signIn our signOut...
[image]

But then the callback is never hit for signOut()...
[image]

Finally, if I try the entire thing from the developer console...

1. Shows gapi.auth2 says I am logged in
2. Manual sign out command
3. Shows gapi.auth2 says I am STILL logged in
   [image]

How can this code be modified to make signOut() work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Calendar API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
</head>
<body>

<p>Google Calendar API Quickstart</p>

<!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
<button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
<button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

<pre id="content"></pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    var CLIENT_ID = 'MY OAUTH CLIENT ID';

    // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
    var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];

    // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
    // included, separated by spaces.
    var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

    var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
    var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

    /**
     *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
     */
    function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
    }

    /**
     *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
     *  listeners.
     */
    function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
            discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
            // Listen for sign-in state changes.
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

            // Handle the initial sign-in state.
            updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
            authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
            signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        });
    }

    /**
     *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
     *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
     */
    function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
            signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
            listUpcomingEvents();
        } else {
            authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
            signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign in the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
    }

    /**
     *  Sign out the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
    }

    /**
     * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
     * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
     *
     * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
     */
    function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
    }

    /**
     * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
     * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
     * appropriate message is printed.
     */
    function listUpcomingEvents() {
        gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
            'calendarId': 'primary',
            'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
            'showDeleted': false,
            'singleEvents': true,
            'maxResults': 10,
            'orderBy': 'startTime'
        }).then(function (response) {
            var events = response.result.items;
            appendPre('Upcoming events:');

            if (events.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                    var event = events[i];
                    var when = event.start.dateTime;
                    if (!when) {
                        when = event.start.date;
                    }
                    appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
                }
            } else {
                appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
            }
        });
    }

</script>

<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
        onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
        onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [revoking token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) HTTP/REST method:

> To programmatically revoke a token, your application makes a request
>   to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke and includes the token
>   as a parameter:

```
curl -H "Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
        https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```

> The token can be an access token or a refresh token. If the token is
>   an access token and it has a corresponding refresh token, the refresh
>   token will also be revoked.

Comment: That works.  However, I would like to do it through the JS API.  How is that done?

Comment: Try the Javascript sample [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent) where you use GoogleAuth.disconnect();  where    GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Strange the signOut doesn't work.  Seems straightforward enough.

Comment: I see your point. But a method doesnt work unless someone writes it specifically. In this case, the method name chosen by the coder was disconnect() not signOut().

Answer (score 0):

other option is to add this to the webpage :

```html
<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function() {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
</script>
```

More info in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in